# BigQuery ML Standard Scaler "failed to calculate mean"

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Trying to build a logistic regression using BigQuery ML, I get the following error:

> Failed to calculate mean since the entries in corresponding column 'x' are all NULLs.

Here's a reproducible query - make sure to change your dataset name:

```sql
CREATE MODEL `samples.TEST_MODELS_001`
TRANSFORM (
    flag,
split_col,
ML.standard_scaler(SAFE_CAST(x as FLOAT64)) OVER() as x
)
OPTIONS
  ( MODEL_TYPE='LOGISTIC_REG',
    AUTO_CLASS_WEIGHTS=TRUE,
    INPUT_LABEL_COLS=['flag'],
    EARLY_STOP=true,
    DATA_SPLIT_METHOD='CUSTOM',
    DATA_SPLIT_COL='split_col',
    L2_REG = 0.3) AS
SELECT
    *
    ,train_test_split = 0 as split_col
FROM (
  select
    0 as train_test_split, 1 as flag, "" as x
   union all
   select 0, 0, "0"
   union all
   select 0, 1, "1"
   union all
   select 1, 1, ""
   union all
   select 1, 0, ""
   union all
   select 1, 1, "1"
)
```

The problem seems to be related to scaling because if I use `ML.MIN_MAX_SCALER` instead of `ML.STANDARD_SCALER` it works as expected. Not sure why this is happening as clearly not all values of `x` are `NULLs` inside the train-test split groups.

I'm wondering if this actually a bug or if I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ML.STANDARD_SCALER function outside the TRANSFORM, it correctly returns the result. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-preprocessing-functions#mlstandard_scaler) on this function:

> When this is used in a TRANSFORM clause, the STDDEV and MEAN calculated to standardize the expression are automatically used in prediction.

Which means, that it had to calculate a MEAN and STDDEV to get the result in the first place, so it seems it should work.

I reported it as a BigQuery issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/165824415). I suggest to subscribe to the issue tracker in order to receive notifications whenever there's an update from the BigQuery team.

## Update

This was answered in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/165824415).

The ML.STANDARD_SCALER function is applied over the training data, after the split. This means that the correct SQL that applies is as follows:

```
-- training data: 1, null, null

select  ml.standard_scaler(x) over() from (select 1 as x)
union all select null as x
union all select null as x

-- Result:
-- null
-- null
-- null
```

That's the reason why the message mentioned the null columns. You can further see that this is the case by adding one record to "0" value to x column for the training data.

```
CREATE MODEL `samples.TEST_MODELS_001`
TRANSFORM (
    flag,
split_col,
ML.standard_scaler(SAFE_CAST(x as FLOAT64)) OVER() as x
)
OPTIONS
  ( MODEL_TYPE='LOGISTIC_REG',
    AUTO_CLASS_WEIGHTS=TRUE,
    INPUT_LABEL_COLS=['flag'],
    EARLY_STOP=true,
    DATA_SPLIT_METHOD='CUSTOM',
    DATA_SPLIT_COL='split_col',
    L2_REG = 0.3) AS
SELECT
    *
    ,train_test_split = 0 as split_col
FROM (
  select
    0 as train_test_split, 1 as flag, "" as x
   union all
   select 0, 0, "0"
   union all
   select 0, 1, "1"
   union all
   select 1, 1, ""
   union all
   select 1, 0, ""
   union all
   select 1, 1, "1"
   union all
   select 1, 1, "0"
)
```